# How Do I Add a Mapped Network Drive to a USB Stick

Tags: networking, hard-drive, usb, shortcuts

I'd like to add a network drive I have mapped so that the shortcut to that drive will appear on a USB stick.  I'd like to be able to access this drive on other computers without having to map it again (and as some user permissions don't allow you to map drives).
Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?  Mapped drives don't appear on other drives, they are maintained by the OS.  You want the act of inserting a usb stick to somehow kick off the process of mapping a drive?

Comment: I'm running windows 7.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to click a command/file to map a new network drive, that has the same properties as one I currently have on my laptop.  My work has locked down this function in the computer window.
@Paul

Answer (score 1):

It won't work the way you are thinking.

Windows shortcuts "point to" things.  So they can point to a drive mapping, but that drive mapping must exist or be created beforehand.  If it's not, Windows will complain it cannot find the target.

If you know the UNC path that it's being mapped from, you can always type that directly in an Explorer window, e.g. if your workplace has a file server accessible via \\mycorp\files\important that's mapped to something like K:, just press the Windows key + E and copy \\mycorp\files\important in the address bar.  If you have permissions, you can still get to it even though it's not "on" a drive letter.

If your workplace hides the C:\ drive from view, your strategy will totally circumvent that for local drives only.